# Django. Creating a registration form. cannot import name 'views'

Tags: django, python-3.x

Good day! When I try to go to the registration page i have error

http://127.0.0.1:8000/registrate

```
ImportError at /registrate
No module named 'registrate'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/registrate
Django Version: 1.8.4
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named 'registrate'
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py in import_module, line 109
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['/home/while1pass/project/smartcms',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Project structure

```
 smartcms/
├── db.sqlite3
├── __init__.py
├── login
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── login
│   │       └── login.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── registration
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── forms.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-34.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── registration
│   │       └── registrate.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── smartcms
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── settings.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── urls.cpython-34.pyc
    │   └── wsgi.cpython-34.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

File smartcms/smartcms/urls.py with module views

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^registrate/', include('registrate.urls')),
    )
```

File smartcms/registration/urls.py with module views

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.RegisterFormView.as_view()),
)
```

tell me, please,  where I made mistakes

**UPD1: After edits urls.py an error**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/registrate

importError at /registrate
cannot import name 'RegistrationForm'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/registrate
Django Version: 1.8.4
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name 'RegistrationForm'
Exception Location: /home/while1pass/project/smartcms/registration/views.py in <module>, line 6
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['/home/while1pass/project/smartcms',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

/smartcms/registration/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.RegisterFormView.as_view()),
)
```

/smartcms/smartcms/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^registrate/', include('registration.urls')),
)
```

/smartcms/registration/forms.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class RegisterFormView(FormView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = "/login/"
    template_name = "registrate.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(RegisterFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

file views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .forms import RegistrationForm

def registrate(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse('Форма верна!')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'registrate.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: See the answer to the russian version


http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/449248/django-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%A1annot-import-name-views

Answer (score 0):

1) try relative: `from .views import RegisterFormView`

2) or `from app_name.views import RegisterFormView` . In this case your app should be on python path.